# Obtaining private key from mnemonic keywords

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed

A customer of us can't remember which wallet he has used before (in 2014), but he still knows his public wallet address and als the 12 words for recovery.

We have a choice of 3 different wallets which he might have used (at least on of those must be the right one)

- Bitwallet for IOS (still available but not devooped / maintained anymore0 We manage to retostore this app from a icloud backup but id holds another wallet)
- blockchain.info (we tried to import using the 12 words, but we got also another wallter address than the one which holds the 0.9 BTC)
- Multibit for Windows (Als tried to import using the words, but we don;t have any backup files so  we've let it generate but also it created another walletadress)

What we really know is the correct walletadress and also the 12 words. Is this enough to recover the private key / funds?

Hope someone can help us out.

Regards, Mark

Answer (score 0):

> **What we really know is the correct walletadress and also the 12 words. Is this enough to recover the private key / funds?**

As you have found, with HD wallets, you also need to know the "derivation path"  -- which usually means knowing the software or service used and sometimes the version. You can find commonly used derivation paths using a web search.

You may also need to adjust the address gap limit so that the HD wallet can discover all addresses with funds. This may require a rescan.

Answer (score 0):

Used https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ Enter your 12 / 24 Seeds Select Address and you can see address and privatekey there